# Why does setting LinearGradientBrush.WrapMode to Clamp fail with ArgumentException ("parameter is not valid")?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

Here's an example:

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

          LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0,0,100,100),Color.Blue, Color.White,angle:0);
          brush.WrapMode = WrapMode.Tile; // OK
          brush.WrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp; // Causes Unhandled exception alert, offering break
    }
```

In the VS2008 output window this shows:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>   Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

(pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/51a43.png)

This is on Windows 7.

Documentation here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.wrapmode(v=vs.90).aspx

confirms LinearGradientBrush.WrapMode accepts a WrapMode

"Gets or sets a WrapMode enumeration that indicates the wrap mode for this 
LinearGradientBrush."

and this 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.drawing2d.wrapmode(v=vs.90).aspx

confirms that WrapMode.Clamp is valid for gradient:

"Clamp  The texture or gradient is not tiled."

Comment: I can confirm this with VS15 on W8.1. This looks like a bug, as `Clamp` ie untiled continuation with, probably the last color would be quite useful.  You can try to workaround with `InterpolationColors` but that requires some knowledge of the sizes to fill..

Comment: Thanks. Please enter your response as an Answer so I can accept it.

Comment: That's an odd error.  You can try creating a bitmap tile of your LinearGradientBrush and then use that bitmap in a TextureBrush, which does not throw an error when it's WrapMode is set for Clamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm this with VS2015 on Windows 8.1.

This looks like a bug to me, as `Clamp` i.e. untiled continuation with, probably the last color would be quite useful.

You can try to workaround with `InterpolationColors` but that requires some knowledge of the sizes to fill..

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors/30341521?s=2|0.5485#30341521) and espcially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025026/how-to-fill-the-linear-gradient-brush-region-from-the-original-region/29029663?s=7|0.1552#29029663) for code examples for using `InterpolationColors`

**Update:** Lars' idea looks also very interesting: Create a tile with the `LinearGradientBrush`  and then use it with a `TextureBrush`..

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine to scale the vector and repeat the end colors, using `SetInterpolationColors` (C++). I leave a space of 10 * VectorSize at both ends and normalize the stops.

[image: GridientClamp]

[image]